# How to apply conditional aggregation in SQL the following scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table:

1. tbDepatrment 2. tbEmployee

Result needed:

```
Department     Employees(by department)    Male(By department)      Female(by department)
Employee         11                            6                         5
Management       10                            5                         5
Owner            1                             1                         0
```

I used this:

```
SELECT [tbDepartment].[DepartmentName] AS [Department name],
       Count(*) AS [Number of employees by department type],
       (Select Count([EmployeeGender]) FROM [tbEmployee] WHERE [EmployeeGender] = 'Male' AND [DepartmentName] = [tbDepartment].[DepartmentName]) AS [Number of male employees by department type],
       (Select Count([EmployeeGender]) FROM [tbEmployee] WHERE [EmployeeGender] = 'Female' AND [DepartmentName] = [tbDepartment].[DepartmentName]) AS [Number of female employees by department type]
FROM [tbEmployee] JOIN [tbDepartment] 
ON [tbEmployee].[DepartmentId] = [tbDepartment].[DepartmentId]
GROUP BY [tbDepartment].[DepartmentName];
```

Resulted as:

```
Department     Employees(by department)    Male(By department)      Female(by department)
Employee         11                            12                         10
Management       10                            12                         10
Owner            1                             12                         10
```

How to display 3rd and 4th column according to the 1st column or grouped by column?

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @swe I changed my question..If still needs improvement change it or suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need subqueries to tally the number of males and females.  Instead, use `CASE` expressions with conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT [tbDepartment].[DepartmentName] AS [Department name],
   COUNT(*) AS [Number of employees by department type],
   SUM(CASE WHEN [EmployeeGender] = 'Male'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Number of male employees by department type],
   SUM(CASE WHEN [EmployeeGender] = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Number of female employees by department type]
FROM [tbEmployee] JOIN [tbDepartment] 
    ON [tbEmployee].[DepartmentId] = [tbDepartment].[DepartmentId]
GROUP BY [tbDepartment].[DepartmentName];
```

**Update:**

While conditional aggregation as I have in the answer above is the way to go here, I actually don't know why your subqueries were giving the wrong output.  The output you are getting is the total number of males and females in *all* departments, for each department.  The output you are getting would be consistent with subqueries of the form:

```
SELECT COUNT([EmployeeGender])
FROM [tbEmployee]
WHERE [EmployeeGender] = 'Male'
```

i.e. *without* the department check.  Maybe you should check your original query to see if it matches what you posted here.

Comment: For update:  I checked it. It gives total count of males and females of complete table and not filtering with department type(not far each department).